# Max pool size was reached. Sql Server, c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asynchronous, connection-pooling

I have encountered the following exception: 'Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached' in my ASP.NET Framework 4.7.2 application. I was trying to investigate the issue with connection leaks in my code myself and I think that it is an error in async calls in the code that as a result connection can not be closed.

Dapper: v1.60.6.
Connection string: `data source=data_source;Initial Catalog=Catalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=login;Password=password; multipleactiveresultsets=true; Connection Timeout=300; Max Pool Size=200`

Code that creates SqlConnection instance (GetConnectionString() method returns string that was pointed above.:

```
protected async Task<T> WithConnection<T>(Func<IDbConnection, Task<T>> getData)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
                {
                    return await getData(connection); // Asynchronously execute getData, which has been passed in as a Func<IDBConnection, Task<T>>
                }
            }
            catch (TimeoutException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{GetType().FullName}.WithConnection() experienced a SQL timeout", ex);
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{GetType().FullName}.WithConnection() experienced a SQL exception (not a timeout)", ex);
            }
        }
```

Usage of this method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetUsersAsync(Filter filter, Config config)
        {
            const string storedProcedure = "[dbo].[GetUsers]";

            var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
            parameters.Add("@param1", config.Value, DbType.String);
            parameters.Add("@param2", filter.Value, DbType.String);

            return await WithConnection(async c => await c.QueryAsync<User>(storedProcedure, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure));
 }
```

Comment: Have you checked how many connections are open ?  You can use [sp_whoisactive](https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive/blob/master/who_is_active.sql)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with async/await but `WithConnection` doesn't seem to do much more than rethrow with less information. I suspect there are other problems in the code - why use `QueryAsync<objec>`? Why specify parameters explicitly instead of using an anonymous type, if the size or type doesn't change? Something else is going on too, resulting in leaked connections

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `connection.Open()` somewhere? Or if Dapper does this automatically, then considier this comment not written :-)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, `object` was used for example of usage, I have edited object types to Users, it may be more clear now. And what's about the second question I don't really understand, what's the difference to use the anonymous type instead of dynamic parameters from Dapper or when can I get more information about it?

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts Thank you for the SQL script. I will be using it

Comment: When is this exception happening? At first call or after many calls?

Comment: @tymtam It happens after many calls

Comment: My bet is that the problem is not related to this method and you have some code using the database that doesn't use `WithConnection`.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am having the same issue with Dapper as well after many calls.